# What is the antiderivative of $t^\alpha \cos (t), \ 0<\alpha <1$?

Tags: integration

For example, what is the antiderivative of $t^{0.3} \cos (t)$?
Of course this is the real part of $t^{0.3} e^{it}$

Comment: Originally I was thinking about an antiderivative. But a definite integral also helps.

Comment: What is the range of integration? Anyway, look up "Mellin transform", it should be interesting for you.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited the question

Comment: Consider $\Re \int t^a e^{it}\,dt$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, i know it's the real part of that, but there's the same question about your integral... I think negro's suggestion about Mellin transform is a good one.

Comment: Yes for sure. You also have thé incomplète gamma function

Comment: There is a solution if you accept the incomplete gamma function. You can find a step-by-step guide for this, e.g. [here](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=t%5E%7Balpha%7D%20cos%28t%29&intvar=t).

Comment: As mentioned above regarding the Mellin transform, this has been adressed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912258/provide-us-a-detailed-explanation-to-calculate-the-mellin-transform-of-a-cosine

Comment: This is the [Bohmer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236160/integral-of-cos-sqrtx3) integral

Answer (score 1):

**Incomplete Gamma Function**
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int t^\alpha \cos t d t \\
= & \operatorname{Re} \int_0^t x^\alpha e^{-i x} d x \\
\stackrel{ i x \rightarrow x }{=}&  \operatorname{Re} \int_0^{t i}\left(\frac{x}{i}\right)^\alpha e^{-x} \frac{d x}{i} \\
= & \operatorname{Re}\left[(-i)^{\alpha+1} \int_0^{it} x^\alpha e^{-x} d x\right] \\
= & \operatorname{Re}\left[(-i)^{\alpha+1}(\Gamma(\alpha+1)-\Gamma(\alpha+1, i t))\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!

Comment: Hi Lai, I'm confused about your last step. Looking at this wiki page about incomplete gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function
The integral is defined over the real numbers (represented by t on the wiki page, and the upper bound x should be a real number), what do you mean by 'i t' as an upper bound? I'm not familiar with the gamma function, just asking.